# How to conditionally initialize a static array

Tags: java, spring

I am working with some code that I would prefer not to change more than necessary. But I've run into a problem. I want to change the contents of `arrayOfStrings` depending on a condition `isConditionMet()`. I cannot do this in a static initialization block.

```
class Scratch {
  static final String[] arrayOfStrings = {"one", "two", "three"};
  //...
}
```

How might I set the contents of the array conditionally without using a constructor or changing the data structure?

Comment: *"I cannot do this in a static initialization block."* - why? Without static block and without a constructor and without changing the structure: you are out of options.

Comment: If `isConditionMet` is not static, you cannot use it in a static context. You could have the static default, remove the final modifier, and update whenever `isConditionMet` is available.

Comment: what is `isConditionMet`?

Comment: @luk2302 I was doing it wrong. Fixed now with help from the selected answer.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko isConditionMet() checks if a property was set in the properties file of a Spring application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `isConditionMet` must be *also* `static`, otherwise you *cannot* instantiate the array based on such condition result from a method.

Then you can use a ternary conditional operator:

```
static final String[] arrayOfStrings = isConditionMet() ? 
        new String[]{"one", "two", "three"} :             // fill in values if 'true'
        new String[]{};                                   // empty if 'false'
```

... or a static initialization block (IMHO, more readable in *this particular* case):

```
static final String[] arrayOfStrings;

static {
    arrayOfStrings = isConditionMet() ? 
            new String[]{"one", "two", "three"} :
            new String[]{};
}
```

**Remember**: If the array is `static`, the method (and  initialization block) must be also `static`. If the array is `non-static`, the method *can* be either `static`/`non-static`, but the initialization block must be *also* `non-static` if used.